# Developing a plug-in for Xamarin.Foms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to start developing a plug-in (similar to library) for Xamarin.Forms. The plug-in should support iOS, Android and UWP.

Because I am a newbie in Xamarin, I don't know where to start and how to create a project for the plug-in in Visual Studio 2015.

Which one is right for me to create a project for Xamarin.Forms application 
supporting iOS, Android and UWP ?

Xamarin Project Creation:

[image: Xamarin Project Creation]

Comment: Have you looked at any Xamarin plugin projects on GitHub? Any widely downloaded one should give a pretty good template.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents#create-a-plugin-for-xamarin

Comment: @Jason RIP lmgtfy links, right?